# ICE Connection failed for webrtc in flutter

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I have been trying to implement video call using webrtc and node.js + socket (for signalling).
Both offer and answer is being created and the "sdp" is being successfully sent to each end. Even ice candidate are being transferred on both sides but still the it fails at last.

An unexpected behaviour is also seen that it connects sometimes but then disconnects on next call and so on..

I am using **flutter-webrtc** package for implementation.